# How to display all photos from gallery using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to display all the photos from the gallery, how can this be done? 
I tried to use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_gallery and https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery, but when I open the screen with one of these packages, the application crashes. 
Can you tell me the working package or how to output all the images from the gallery??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code of what you’ve tried?

Comment: @returnVoid, I am using this code [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_gallery#-example-tab-)